# where to model in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, blender, modeling

I'm a new game dev and I want to start creating object, character, environment. what should I use
a built in editor like proBuilder or separate editors like blender, which one is better for the long run or I should design simple object in probuilder and complex shapes in blender because of time required to import from blender or importing doesn't make a difference

thanks in advance

Comment: Off-topic because this is a "life question" - no right answer here. In general, the tool you should be using is the one you're competent with. If you don't have any experience with proBuilder or Blender then I'd recommend learning Blender because it's NOT tied to Unity - you can use it for anything. It's got a steep learning curve, though.

Answer (score 0):

ProBuilder let you create 3D assets right in the editor but imo it fits mostly for prototypes or lowPoly style. If you need smth better then these, my choice is Blender3D. Also Maya is good and affordable

Comment: prototype? how do you polish them after creating in probuilder

Comment: for example you need a city, so you build it with cubes and shapes with ProBuilder... then, when you realized that this game worth it, you go to a normal 3D software and create all these houses etc in details. Then replacing ProBuilder cubes to a detailed and textured FBX models.